# request.session is not saved in Django,, but updateprice is show in console.log()

Tags: html, jquery, json, python-3.x

please, session cannot be set properly.
I am trying since 1 month. but I cannot seem to get it.
I go to the detail page and type length & width shown the total amount, multiplying the length and width money is shown according to the area. but that total money is not saved in the cart. but amount saved in the cart is 1 square feet(1sqt). I booked a wallpaper its length is 10 feet. Its width is 10 feet and whatever its total amount comes, it will not be saved in the cart. the amount shown in the cart is showing 1 square feet...

**python**

```
def add_to_cart(request):
    print("Start add_to_cart")  # Debug statement

    # del request.session['cartdata']
    request.session.modified = True

    cart_p={}

    updated_price = float(request.session.get('updatedPrice', 0))  # Use 0 as default if updatedPrice is not set
    print("Updated Price:", updated_price)  # Debug statement


    cart_p[str(request.GET['id'])] = {
        'image': request.GET['image'],
        'title': request.GET['title'],
        'qty': request.GET['qty'],
        'price': updated_price,  # Use the updated price here
    }
```

**product_detail.html**

```
<main class="container my-4">
    <!-- Featured Products -->
    <h3 class="my-4 border-bottom pb-1">{{data.title}}</h3> <div class="row">
        <!-- Images -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <img id="zoom_01" data-zoom-image="/media/{{data.productattribute_set.first.image}}" src="/media/{{data.productattribute_set.first.image}}" class="card-img-top" alt="{{data.title}}">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <p>{{data.detail}}</p>
            <hr/>
            <table class="table table-bordered">
                <tr>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>$ <span class="product-price-{{data.id}}">{{data.productattribute_set.first.price}}</span></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
        <!-- Include child_template.html -->
        {% include 'calculator.html' %}
                    </th>
                </tr>


            </table>
    <hr/>
            <div class="input-group my-3" style="width:30%;">
              <input type="number" value="1" class="form-control product-qty-{{data.id}}" id="productQty" />
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <input type="hidden" class="product-image-{{data.id}}" value="{{data.productattribute_set.first.image}}" />
                  <input type="hidden" class="product-id-{{data.id}}" value="{{data.id}}" />
                  <input type="hidden" class="product-title-{{data.id}}" value="{{data.title}}" />
                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm add-to-cart" data-index="{{data.id}}" type="button" id="addToCartBtn"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Add to Cart</button>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**calculator.html**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Function to calculate area and price
  function calculate() {
      var length = parseFloat($('#id_length').val());
      var width = parseFloat($('#id_width').val());
      var area = Math.round(length * width);
  
      var price_per_square_feet = parseFloat($('.product-price-{{data.id}}').text());  // Get the price per square feet
      var price = Math.round(area * price_per_square_feet);  // Calculate the price based on area and price per square feet
  
      sessionStorage.setItem('updatedPrice', price);
  
      $('#area').val(area);
      $('#price').val(price);
  }
```